# Transposition Cipher Advanced Application Inquiry

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, encryption, python-requests

I faced some problems while trying to make some further applications on the transposition cipher. I wanted to create a program that allows me to cipher the "secret code" with unknown key. Although I was able to devise a way to print out all the possible code, it was too long and tedious to search for the correct plain text.

Thus, I wanted to read the text file named dictionary (which includes all words from the dictionary) and compare the printed codes to figure out one and only correct answer code. In other words, I would want the Python program to check all the words from printed codes and if included in the dictionary, print it out.

Here is my project so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
my_dictionary = open(Path.home() / 'dictionary.txt', 'r')
my_words = my_dictionary.read()
my_dictionary.close()

cipher_text = 'A ohtsS ommyvt t i nt snat,tcfps eonroaa eseere ro u,nr uiflrudtq arsimdt etnmntles ruocsynmaeae ubgey ediert,mgotrndsmesn trann e bsna d tbr ,wa-tgcmrno   p tresf hkga eosulafirwoir aeeie.i r msronoe nstisnnnAsoe(b)er g cg orp geA f le. mcrmoso lew rAa cer a oaan rsyceiaA'
plain_text = ''
key = len(cipher_text)

for u in range(1, key):
    divider = int(len(cipher_text)/u)
    for k in range(divider):
        for i in range(u):
            plain_text += cipher_text[k + i*divider]
    print(plain_text)
```

Comment: 1. check all words ---- cipher_text_words = cipher_text.split(' ') 2. what is the meaning of the 'divider' ? 3. your current code seems confusing compared to problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is that you have so many possible ciphertexts and you hope that one of them is the plaintext so you want an automated checking program that will extract this possible ciphertext from the rest by comparing it's words to a dictionery if this is what you want I guess this modified program will help you a little. **read the comments**

```
from pathlib import Path
import re
import random
my_dictionary = open(Path.home() / 'dictionary.txt', 'r')

    # convert all to lower so that casing doesnt matter.
    # better to save the result to file so that you dont have to do
    # this every time to improve effiency.
my_words = my_dictionary.read().lower()
my_dictionary.close()

    # convert all to lower case.
cipher_text = 'A ohtsS ommyvt t i nt snat,tcfps eonroaa eseere ro u,nr uiflrudtq arsimdt etnmntles ruocsynmaeae ubgey ediert,mgotrndsmesn trann e bsna d tbr ,wa-tgcmrno   p tresf hkga eosulafirwoir aeeie.i r msronoe nstisnnnAsoe(b)er g cg orp geA f le. mcrmoso lew rAa cer a oaan rsyceiaA'.lower()

    # split the ciphertext at words boundries so a,b are two different words a and b.
cipher_text = re.findall(r"[\w']+", cipher_text)
plain_text = ''

length = len(cipher_text) -1
found = 0

    # Try 3 times.
for word in range(3):
    x = random.randint(0, length)
    if cipher_text[x] in my_dictionary:
        found += 1

            # if found words are 2 or 3 then the ciphertext is propably plaintext.
        if found >= 2:
            print("[+] Found One result of cipher Text that looks like plaintext")
            print("=> ciphertext: {}".format(" ".join(cipher_text)))
```

Also note that this program will only compare one ciphertext to plaintext and has complexity of `O(n)`(n is number of words in dictionary) but if you will compare `v` ciphertexts it will `O(vn)` which can be time consuming so it's better if you can use another efficient searching algorithm or data structure such as dict or set.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the quality answer. It definitely helps me a lot.

Comment: I've been just going over your advice again and if it doesn't bother you, may I ask what "length = len(cipher_text) -1" exactly does?

Comment: @pythonnoobie ```len()``` function return number of elements in array while array indices start counting at zero(first element) so, you need to offset by subtracting one.

Comment: @pythonnoobie You can upvote or mark the answer as correct if you find it helpful.

Comment: Haha i've tried but the system does not let me do the up button because I do not have 15 rep(?) yet